# Google Analytics not generating data

Tags: google-analytics

I'm new to Google Analytics. Yesterday, I created an account and I pointed it to our website. I've added the JavaScript codes that Google Analytics generated for us. I put the code on all of our .html files.

I've been hitting our website from outside and so does my officemates since last night and also today. However, when I visited https://www.google.com/analytics under Reporting, everything was showing 0. I don't see any single spike at all.

Comment: Google Analytics takes a few days to initiate and set accounts, I've set accounts up and they've had 2/3 days of no results before everything suddenly appears. Have a look on Friday and it'll almost certainly be there.

Comment: Are you able to share your site to review your code setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend navigating to the Reporting -> Realtime -> Overview tab within your Google Analytics (GA) account. This is an almost realtime view into users on your site. In a separate tab access your site and refresh the page, this page view event should then be visible in the GA Realtime view.

If you can see your page view then its likely that you've inserted the correct GA script into your page and that you've used the correct GA property id. If you cant see your own page view then you will know that your script is incorrectly inserted or your GA property id is incorrect.

Last bit of advice: GA often has a 24-48 delay before you are able to use its full suite of insight tools (such as GA Goals). If you're expecting to see Goals populate immediately you're gonna have a bad time.

Last-last bit of advice: make sure that you select the current date from the date range picker in the top right of the GA Reporting view. It defaults to yesterday.

Comment: Ok, I will access it again in few days. I didn't know Google takes a while before we'll see the changes. I'll keep everyone posted. :) Thanks!

Comment: I also see a 200 OK on this ajax call inside Chrome Dev tools - http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&_v=j37&a=14579 which I think is a good sign. I didn't paste the whole link